# 40 days at the Kotel

Tags: tefilla, zemanim, segulah, kotel-western-wall

If someone is trying to pray [40 consecutive days at the Kotel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55458/40-consecutive-days-of-prayer-at-the-western-wall), does beginning prayer one minute after sunset count for the day that's ending? For the day that's starting? Both? Neither?

Comment: Tuvya, welcome to Mi Yodeya! I recommend that you consult your rabbi for spiritual guidance regarding the best way to do and keep track of your special davening. We can't recommend how you, personally, should proceed in your particular situation, so I am editing the question to make it more general. If it's not consistent with your intent, please [edit] further. I sincerely hope your prayers are answered for the best.

Comment: It really just depends what the rules of your acceptance were. Anyone can accept to do anything with its own rules. What are you accepting to do?

Comment: If he is beginning prayer all 40 days one minute after sunset what difference does it make?

Answer (score 1):

As the [question you linked to](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55458/501) states, this is a recent custom and essentially it depends on why you are doing *40 days at the Kotel*.

If you made a vow, then it would depend on what you had in mind. If you didn't think about this *trick* then it would go by *how most  people would interpret it*. Most people assume (as far as I know) that *40 days at the Kotel* mean you have to make the effort to go 40 consecutive days to the Kotel.

This is called: בִּנְדָרִים הַלֵּךְ אַחַר לְשׁוֹן בְּנֵי אָדָם

But even if you had in mind to simply pray 40 consecutive days at the Kotel, with on 20 trips, you probably can't do it right before & after sunset.

I have been taught that the Yerushalmim consider the first 13 minutes after sunset as day (and in a pinch you can Daven Mincha then).

18 minutes after sunset you can already daven Maariv without repeating Shma. I assume the 5 minutes between are *Bein Hashmashot - twilight*.

So if you want to do *40 days at the Kotel* in 20 days, you probably need to pray for a few moments before sunset (or within the 13 minutes thereafter in emergency), and then again 18 minutes after sunset.