# Nishmas Kol Chai for 40 Days

Tags: segulah

Does anyone know where the [Segulah to say Nishmas Kol Chai for 40 days](https://www.nishmas.net) comes from? Apparently it is mentioned in the name of Rebbetzin Kanievsky, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55458/1739

Answer (score 4):

I haven't found the source for why specifically 40 days, but in [this essay](https://www.machonso.org/hamaayan/?gilayon=17&id=760), [Rabbi Stel](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%9C) explains the origins of the segulah of saying Nishmat for any sort of trouble that befalls a person. It's long and in Hebrew, so I'll give a short summary in English:

> The second aspect of the segulah, that relates it to any sort of trouble that befalls a person...was brought by [Rabbi Eliezer Papo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_Papo) in his book "Chesed L'alafim": "We have a kabbalah (tradition) in our hands from R"Y Hachassid (Rabbi Yehudah Hachassid) that the praise 'Nishmat Kol Chai' is suitable for any trouble, for a person to accept upon himself that when he shall be saved from it he shall say 'Nishmat Kol Chai' in thanks and voice of song before ten [men]. And with this many were saved." (Chesed L'alafim, Orach Chaim, [siman 281, seif katan 4](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7849&st=&pgnum=502&hilite=)).

> Though Rabbi Eliezer Papo isn't the originator of this 'kabbalah'...many copied from his book, such as: [The Kaf Hachaim, the Ben Ish Chai...], but the original source for this segulah appears in the book [Chemdat Yamim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemdat_Yamim)...written anonymously and even suspected of Sabbateanism and is greatly controversial. In it is written:

> "And in its might, many Anshei Shem were able to receive a prophetic speech in their mouths through the yichudim and kavanot in the beautiful text 'Nishmat Kol Chai'...and we have a kabbalah [tradition] in our hands from R"Y Hachassid peace be upon him, that it is suitable for any trouble that may not come, for a man to accept upon himself, that when he shall be saved from it, he shall say 'Nishmat Kol Chai' in thanks and voice of song before ten [men]. And with this many were saved. And I have checked and tested this myself." (Chemdat Yamim pt. 1 (for Shabbat and Yom Tov), [Shabbat, ch. 11](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9406&st=&pgnum=149))

Answer (score 0):

There are sources that say if someone is seeking a yeshua (a salvation) from a particularly difficult time they should take on a neder (a vow) to say Nishmas following the ensuing salvation.

It brings down [here](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/57790) that the Ben Ish Chai in תולדות שנה ב, סעיף ג, שו"ת מכתם לדוד אורח חיים סימן יג is a proponent of this idea. And also both the [Kaf Hachaim Orach Chaim 281:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.281.8.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and Rav Chaim Palagi in [Chaim LaRosh](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22746&st=&pgnum=304&hilite=) bring this practise down.